# I am having the same dataset as other person and same code but I m getting error of expecting 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, svm

I m having following code for SVR regressror

```
# SVR

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
"""from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)"""

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

# Fitting SVR to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)

# Visualising the SVR results
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

# Visualising the SVR results (for higher resolution and smoother curve)
X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.01) # choice of 0.01 instead of 0.1 step because the data is feature scaled
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_grid, regressor.predict(X_grid), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

Now I m getting the error for above code like Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  45000.   50000.   60000.   80000.  110000.  150000.  200000.  300000.
  500000. 1000000.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

And If I m reshaping to it before applying feature scaling, it is making 0 to all values.

Comment: I am having the same dataset as other person and same code  but I m getting error of expecting 2D array

Comment: shows the complete error message as it appears.

Comment: yess... this is the complete error after running this file.. from the following link you can download the dataset as well as code  https://www.superdatascience.com/machine-learning/

Comment: You really need to post the whole error, including the stack trace. It's hard to debug the problem with only the error description text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `y` assignment line to:

```
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2:3].values
```

or, following the suggestion of the error message:

```
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```